# Divergence in threads within different blocks in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

Does divergence in threads within different blocks / warps is inefficient or just when the divergence is in the same block / warp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divergency is only withing a warp.
 
Warps within a block can take different branches without diverging. 
See CUDA Programming Guide Chapter 4.1