# Can a branch in CUDA be ignored if all the warps go one path? If so, is there a way I could give the compiler/runtime this information?

Tags: cuda

Suppose we have code like the following (I have not compiled this, it may be wrong)

```
__global__ void myKernel()
{
    int data = someArray[threadIdx.x];
    
    if (data == 0) {
        funcA();
    } else {
        funcB();
    }
}
```

Now Suppose there's 1024-thread block running, and `someArray` is all zero.

Further suppose that `funcB()` is costly to run, but `funcA()` is not.

I assume the compiler has to emit both paths sequentially, like doing funcA first, then funcB after. This is not ideal.

Is there a way to hint to CUDA to not do it? Or does the runtime notice "no threads are active so I will skip over all the instructions as I see them"?

Or better yet, what if the branch was something like this (again, haven't compiled this, but it illustrates what I am trying to convey)

```
__constant__ int constantNumber;

__global__ void myKernel()
{
    if (constantNumber == 123) {
        funcA();
    } else {
        funcB();
    }
}
```

and then I set `constantNumber` to 123 before launching the kernel. Would this still cause both paths to be taken?

Comment: Don't worry about it. There is some cost associated with branches where the compiler cannot prove that all threads take the same way, but it is minor. If no thread in the warp takes the else branch, it will not be executed and no time will be wasted on it.

Comment: @Homer512 That sounds like something you should be writing as an answer instead of in the comments. Are you not confident in that statement to make it an answer? Because if what you said is true, then that directly answers my question.

Comment: I've been hit with downvotes one too many times when giving short answers. At the very least I would have to research quotes from the documentation to prove my point. I am confident in my answer, however. That's the advantage of CUDA's programming model over vectorization, after all. Same as with sequential memory access. It doesn't need to be proven at compile time. If it happens at runtime, you get the desired performance boost.

Comment: BTW: This answer supports my point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350048/divergence-in-threads-within-different-blocks-in-cuda

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using `__builtin_assume`.
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#__builtin_assume

Quoting the documentation:

> `void __builtin_assume(bool exp)`
> Allows the compiler to assume that the Boolean argument is true. If the argument is not true at run time, then the behavior is undefined. The argument is not evaluated, so any side-effects will be discarded.